# Why is this SQL injection harmful?

Tags: mybb

I have a mybb forum that I have found is vulnerable to a SQL injection. I have performed said SQL injection on the site, but I don't understand why this data is sensitive. For security reasons, I have not disclosed my website, but an end ample found in the internet is pictured below. Can someone explain to me why this data should not be publically known?

http://uploaderx.persiangig.com/C/mybb_sqli_error.png

Comment: Because this - http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Which SQL injection you are talking about?

Comment: More specifically, although it's dangerous enough for people to run arbitrary `SELECT` statements it's even worse that they can potentially run **any** DML statement (`DELETE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`).

Comment: @YourCommonSense search.php injection exploit

Comment: @Yuck I'm not very knowledgeable about SQL injection, but how does a search for allow for a select statement? All I see is random numbers and letters

Comment: I have no idea what is search.php injection exploit. And how this image is related to it

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple PHP warning and no SQL Injecetion.

Answer (score 2):

Your data may not be sensitive, but your site would be VERY sensitive to someone issuing a series of DROP TABLE commands through SQL injection. You could very easily find your site nothing but error messages no matter what page you visited.

And if you didn't have a recent backup (you *DO* do frequent backups, right??), your site would be pretty much dead and you would have to start from scratch.